# Firmware for T.V56.03 display controller board with tsumv56ruu-z1 chipset to be used with LP173WF1(TL)(B3)

Tags: display, hardware, firmware

I am searching for a proper firmware for days already.

I recently got my T.V56.03 display controller board with a tsumv56ruu-z1 chipset and I want to use my LP173WF1(TL)(B3) display with it.

As the display is currently looking very weird I assume that the firmware currently onboard is simply incompatible with 2 channel LVDS-connections. I already tried to set another preset of LVDS-map without success.

Surely I can tell you that this is not a hardware-issue as I tried a lot of different settings on that one as well.

[image]
<sup>(click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: I've got the same issue with display "B173HW02 V1" and both controllers "T.VST59.031" and "T.V56.03". Got no solution yet.

Comment: I got the display "B173HW02 V1" although I ordered "LP173WF1 (TL)(B2)" (happened even twice). You should check your display exactly. Maybe you have the wrong display too?

Comment: This question, and these comments, do not belong on this site. @Sven, you  have enough rep on S.O to indicate that you know how S.E sites work.

Comment: @Mawg: I believe that Sven's comment is not just a "me too" as it adds a bit of information (about "T.VST59.031"). About the topicality of firmware recommendations: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/firmware-recommendations

Comment: Having re-read it, I will upvote it, as it adds a modicum of information - viz. the following *does not* work. Aplogoes@SvenReuter

Comment: Hi. General you can play with option General settings->Lvds map and try to change default value. Moreover check this site, maybe you discover something else that might to help: https://sites.google.com/site/lcd4hobby/how-to-start

Answer (score -1):

The correct firmware for T.V56.03 chip is: [tsumv59xus-z1](http://www.datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/search.php?sWord=TSUMV59XUS-Z1).